# cellForRowAtIndexPath never gets called, but numberOfRowsInSection is

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `viewController` with a tableView outlet, and the controller is the `dataSource` of the `tableView`.

When I tried to reload the `tableView` using `tableView.reloadData()`, the dataSource method `numberOfRowsInSection` is called, and in the console I could see that the `numberOfRows` is 1 in both section 0 and section 1. However, the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is not called. (I put a breakpoint in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`).

BTW, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` did get called once when the controller is first loaded.

Can anyone please point me the right direction to look at? been stucked for a while already...

I'm using swift 2.0

Thanks!

Comment: One of the scenario where numberOfRows is called while cellForRowAtIndexPath does not called is when tableview height is zero. Check tableview height when reload method is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please ensure that `tableView.reloadData()` is being called on main thread. If you are already doing this then check that the `UITableView` instance you called `reloadData` on is the same `UITableView` that you have displayed in your view. This is a common cause for `numberOfRowsInSection` getting called but not `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: Yes it's on main thread. However your second suggestion might point to the right direction, since I'm calling the reload method from a separate dataSource class. That class might have a pointer issue with the controller. I don't know how swift 2 handled this yet but I'll try not using the dataSource class, and see if it still happens. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, do let me know once you fix this. Interested to know what fixed it :-)

Comment: Got it. It's not the pointer thing..It's just that the tableView is of the searchResultsController of a searchBar, and the way I loaded the controller into the screen was wrong, so that the tableView never got appeared...Interestingly it still called the numberOfRows, but never the cellForRows.